# C++ print time difference?

Tags: c++, time, libc

In C++ I wrote:

```
time_t tmp1, tmp2;
time(&tmp1);
sleep(1);
time(&tmp2);
std::cout << tmp2-tmp1;
```

But every-time I run it I see 1 printed, why the result is too perfect? shouldn't it contain some milliseconds too?

Comment: Consider using the libraries from `#include <chrono>` to get a timer with milliseconds or microseconds. At the botton of https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono there's an example.

Comment: If `time_t` is more precise than integer count of seconds, use [`difftime()`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/difftime/).

Comment: The `time` function returns an absolute number of seconds (integer), never a floating point value.

Comment: `auto t1 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()); sleep(1); auto t2 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()); std::cout<<(t2 - t1).count();` Try this.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using [`std::chrono::steady_clock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock) to time a function:

```
auto const start       = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
f();
auto const stop        = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
auto const duration    = stop-start;
auto const duration_ms = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(duration);
//                                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^

std::cout << duration_ms.count();
```

Comment: Great answer, though I think `std::chrono::steady_clock` may be preferable for measuring the time of an operation because it is guaranteed not to be modified.

Comment: @Camwin You are right! I intended to write steady_clock but my fingers were typing system_clock

Answer (score 1):

Your system, like many C++ systems, follows the POSIX specification for `time_t` and `time`. The POSIX specification says that a `time_t` will contain the number of seconds since 1/1/1970.

See [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/time.html) for more.

Comment: What if I want something accurate to use for time of insertion (I want to know in A was inserted before B in some data structure) what should I use in this case?

Comment: without using chrono

Comment: @John If your platform has [gettimeofday](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/gettimeofday.html) you can use that.

Comment: Still this prints same for both, I want something really accurate: ```timeval tim{};
    gettimeofday(&tim,nullptr);
    timeval tim2{};
    gettimeofday(&tim2,nullptr);
    std::cout << tim.tv_sec << std::endl;
    std::cout << tim.tv_usec << std::endl;
    std::cout << tim2.tv_sec << std::endl;
    std::cout << tim2.tv_usec << std::endl;```

Comment: output: ```1626658021
697993
1626658021
697993```

Comment: @John Your platform may not have anything that accurate. What platform are you using?

Comment: @John There is no call to `sleep` in the code in your comment.  As a result, everything happens in less than a microsecond.  With the call to `sleep` in place, you do see a difference, see: https://wandbox.org/permlink/9BWbIOpBFTwtiRhm